# 画面回転後にYouTubePlayerのインスタンスがnullになってしまいます｡

Tags: android, youtube-player-api

現在`YouTube Player API`を使ったadnroidアプリを作っているのですが､以下のようなコードでインスタンスを管理しているのですが､画面回転後に参照するとnullになっています｡画面回転後も同じインスタンスを参照することはできますか?

**コード:**

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("onstart", "onstart");
    if(playerInstance==null||player==null){
        //YouTube player apiを初期化
        initYouTube();
    }
}

//Initialize YouTube player
private void initYouTube(){
    //プレイヤを読み込む
    player = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    //プレイヤーを初期化
    player.initialize(apiKey, this);
}
```

**初期化完了時に呼び出されるコールバックメソッド:**

```
//Player関連メソッド
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
    if(!b){
        //ここでインスタンスを保持している｡
        this.playerInstance = youTubePlayer;
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId);
        prevVideoIdList.add(videoId);

        //If it is smart phone and orientation is land, use full screen
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Resources r = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = r.getConfiguration();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
            if((configuration.screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
                    <Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE){
                youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
            }else{
                youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
            }
        }else{
            if(configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp<600){
                youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
            }else{
                youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

画面回転後に以下のメソッドを呼び出すとYouTubePlayerのインスタンスがnullなので`NullPointerException`が出ていしまいます｡

**YouTube Playerインスタンスを参照するメソッド:**

```
//Listener of RelatedVideoFragment
@Override
public void moveActivity(int position){
    playerInstance.loadVideo(relateVideoIds.get(position-1));
    //Update View
    prevVideoIdList.add(relateVideoIds.get(position-1));
    videoId=relateVideoIds.get(position-1);
    //relateVideoIds is initialized, and relateVideoItems is initialized
    relateVideoIds = new ArrayList<>();
    relateVideoItems = new ArrayList<>();
    relateVideoSearch();
}

//If customer push previous video's button, play previous video
@Override
public void playPrev(){
    if(prevVideoIdList!=null&&prevVideoIdList.size()!=1) {
        playerInstance.loadVideo(prevVideoIdList.get(prevVideoIdList.size()-2));
        videoId = prevVideoIdList.get(prevVideoIdList.size()-2);
        prevVideoIdList.remove(prevVideoIdList.size()-2);
        relateVideoIds = new ArrayList<>();
        relateVideoItems = new ArrayList<>();
        relateVideoSearch();
    }else if(prevVideoIdList!=null&&prevVideoIdList.size()==1){
        finish();
    }
}
```

**追記:**

画面回転時にレイアウトを変更するので、AndroidManifestでorientation|ScreenSizeを設定する方法はつかえないとおもいます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moveActivity()`と`playPrev()`を実行した時にYouTubePlayerを初期化するようにしたところ､ひとまず`nullPointerException`は防げました｡ しかしこれだと､次の動画が始まらないので改善が必要であります｡

Comment: 追記:
`onPause`で`playerIntance.release()`を呼び出すことで初期化もうまくいきました｡